# JAX-RS Jackson Json Provider Date Format Issue

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, jackson, resteasy

WRT to the following question:

[Jersey + Jackson JSON date format serialization - how to change the format or use custom JacksonJsonProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428109/jersey-jackson-json-date-serialization-format-problem-how-to-change-the-form).

I wish to know

- Is Jackson specifying that the json date format should be normalised to a unix time integer?

Follow-up questions ...

- Has there been a change in its stance anytime recently?
- Shouldn't a date format be normalised to the same format provided by jaxb xml output?
- why/why not?
- any effort put into resolving this issue?
- has RestEasy provided a json provider mitigation that would output json date in a generally recognisable date format?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry people for yelling out loud - I found the answers here

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling,

here

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ#Serializing_Dates,

here

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers

here

http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/util/StdDateFormat.html

Using the @JsonSerialize(using= ... ) way:

```
public class JsonStdDateSerializer
extends JsonSerializer<Date> {
  private static final DateFormat iso8601Format =
    StdDateFormat.getBlueprintISO8601Format();

  @Override
  public void serialize(
    Date date, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
  throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    // clone because DateFormat is not thread-safe
    DateFormat myformat = (DateFormat) iso8601Format.clone();
    String formattedDate = myformat.format(date);
    jgen.writeString(formattedDate);
  }
}
```

Comment: Someone downvoted this answer. Care to explain why? I don't quite like the answer myself, but those are the recommended way around it. You can't blame me or my answer for the existence of a disagreement between jaxb and jackson. You would have to take your rant out on those two orgs.

Answer (score 2):

This is also controlled by a feature on the ObjectMapper (at least in 1.9.11, and possibly earlier):

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
om.writer().writeValue(System.out, objectWithDateProperty);
```

I don't see how to declaratively do the equivalent on the object definition itself.