# How to hook Jackson ObjectMapper with Guice / Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jackson, guice

I can't seem to get my Jackson ObjectMapper Module registered correctly.

I'm using a Guice + Jersey + Jackson (FasterXML) stack.

I've followed how to customise the ObjectMapper based on various question here. In particular, I have a ContextResolver declared, marked as an @javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider and a @javax.inject.Singleton.

I have a GuiceServletContextListener along the lines of:

```
@Override
protected Injector getInjector() {

     Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new DBModule(dataSource),
            new ServletModule()
            {
                @Override
                protected void configureServlets() {


                    // Mapper
                    bind(JacksonOMP.class).asEagerSingleton();

                    // ... 

                    Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Trace",
                            "true");
                    initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");

                    serve("/services/*").with(
                            GuiceContainer.class,
                            initParams);
                }
            });

    return injector;
}
```

Mapper defined

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Singleton
@Produces
public class JacksonOMP implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

  @Override
  public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> aClass) {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());
    return mapper;
  }
}
```

However - with this configuration alone, getContext() is never called, so the mapper is never registered. I'm stuck in a typical guice--annotations-mystery, where it's practically untraceable to what I'm actually supposed to be doing. Spring users just report registering the component, and the container just picks it up.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428109/jersey-jackson-json-date-serialization-format-problem-how-to-change-the-form) answer talks about overriding my own javax.ws.rs.core.Application implementation. However, this looks hard-wired in the jersey-guice impementation of GuiceContainer to be DefaultResourceConfig():

```
@Override
protected ResourceConfig getDefaultResourceConfig(Map<String, Object> props,
        WebConfig webConfig) throws ServletException {
    return new DefaultResourceConfig();
}
```

Am I supposed subclass GuiceContainer here? Or is there some other magic annotation that I'm missing?

This seems a fairly common thing to want to do - I'm surprised at how hard it's proving to do with this guice combination.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> I'm stuck in a typical guice--annotations-mystery, where it's
>   practically untraceable to what I'm actually supposed to be doing.
>   Spring users just report registering the component, and the container
>   just picks it up.

You really should read [excellent Guice documentation](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Motivation). Guice is very easy to use, it has very small number of basic concepts. Your problem is in that you mixed Jersey JAX-RS dependency injection and Guice dependency injection. If you are using `GuiceContainer` then you declare that you will be using Guice *for all* of your DI, so you have to add bindings with Guice and not with JAX-RS.

For instance, you do not need `ContextResolver`, you should use plain Guice `Provider` instead:

```
import com.google.inject.Provider;

public class ObjectMapperProvider implements Provider<ObjectMapper> {
    @Override
    public ObjectMapper get() {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Then you should add corresponding binding to your module:

```
bind(ObjectMapper.class).toProvider(ObjectMapperProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

This will bind `ObjectMapper`, but it is not enough to use Jersey with Jackson. You will need some kind of `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter`, e.g. `JacksonJsonProvider`. You will need another provider for it:

```
public class JacksonJsonProviderProvider implements Provider<JacksonJsonProvider> {
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Inject
    JacksonJsonProviderProvider(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public JacksonJsonProvider get() {
        return new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper);
    }
}
```

Then bind it:

```
bind(JacksonJsonProvider.class).toProvider(JacksonJsonProviderProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

This is all you need to do - no subclassing is needed.

There is a room for code size optimization though. If I were you I would use `@Provides`-methods:

```
@Provides @Singleton
ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());
    return mapper;
}

@Provides @Singleton
JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    return new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper);
}
```

These methods should be added to one of your modules, e.g. to anonymous `ServletModule`. Then you won't need separate provider classes.
BTW, you should use `JerseyServletModule` instead of plain `ServletModule`, it provides a lot of useful bindings for you.

Comment: This is very helpful. My particular problem was actually that I had *2* jacksons (both codehaus version and the fasterxml version), so the objectmappers were completely ignored because they were of the wrong type.

Comment: I had the same dependencies conflict issue (codehaus+fasterxml) :  `JsonIgnore` was not working at all. In my case, jackson codehaus (jackson-mapper-asl or core-asl) was linked to an azure documentdb package dependency and has been removed completely (by pom exclusion) to keep the latest (fasterxml) version only. Thanks to @user340535 for your comment that help me to fix the JacksonJsonProvider hook !

Comment: For some reason the version with annotations does not work with me in Guice 4 using JerseyGuiceServletContextListener. What can cause it? With normal binding and extra classes it does work with no issue.