# Jackson deserialize Scala Future

Tags: java, java-8, jackson, jersey, jersey-test-framework

I'm trying to figure how to explain Jersey and Jackson how to deserialize a Future that I pass as byte[].

I create my own ContextResolver

```
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private static ObjectMapper mapper = null;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper = ObjectMapperFactory.getObjectMapper();     
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }

}
```

And the implementation of the ObjectMapper

```
public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule futureModule = new SimpleModule("FutureModule");
        futureModule.<Future>addDeserializer(Future.class, new FutureDeserializer<String>());
        defaultObjectMapper.registerModule(futureModule);
        return defaultObjectMapper;
}
```

And then finally in the implementation of my FutureDeserializer

```
public class FutureDeserializer<T> extends StdDeserializer<Future<T>>{

    public FutureDeserializer() {
        super(Future.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Future<T> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper=(ObjectMapper)jp.getCodec();
        //TODO: Breakpoint never stop here
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then I register in my `ResourceConfig` before start the `JerseyTest`

```
ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig();
        rc.register(SpringLifecycleListener.class);
        rc.register(RequestContextFilter.class);
        rc.register(new JacksonFeature());
        rc.register(new ObjectMapperContextResolver());
```

But when I run the test the ObjectMapperContextResolver is invoked and the mapper returned to Jersey, but he never use the FutureDeserializer.

Any idea what I´m doing wrong?

Comment: Your code doesn't show where you are using the ObjectMapper to de-serialize. Also, how you de-serialize is not clear, since the method is just returning null.

Comment: Also, take a look at if it helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757724/how-to-hook-jackson-objectmapper-with-guice-jersey?rq=1