# JAVA Rest two dates Path param or Query param

Tags: java, rest, parameters

I have a rest service which validates date now i need to modify it to take two dates, but i don't know if to use `@PathParam` or `@QueryParam` and if i can insert it between two `@PathParam`
This it the original code :

```
 @Path("isDateValid/{date}/{itemId}")
    public boolean isDateValid(@PathParam("date") Date date, @PathParam("itemId") Long itemId) {
```

Should i do like this :

```
 @Path("isDateValid/{startDate}/{endDate}/{itemId}")
    public boolean isDateValid(@PathParam("startDate") Date startDate, @PathParam("endDate") Date endDate, @PathParam("itemId") Long itemId) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use third party stuff, I suggest you define a format for the text-date. You can use the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class (avoid the space). The you can use the following code.

```
@Path("isDateValid/{itemId}")
public boolean isDateValid(@PathParam("itemId") Long itemId) {
    @QueryParam("begin") String sBegin; 
    @QueryParam("end") String sEnd;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(/* Your patern, for example "yyMMddHHmmssZ"*/);

    Date dBegin = sdf.parse(sBegin);
    Date dEnd = sdf.parse(sEnd);

/*
...
*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Date Class is cannot serialize using JAX-RS as it is not a simple type. You need to develop the same using MessageBodyReader/Writer .
[Click Here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html)  for more

Or you can use some third party stuff to configure to get it done.

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428109/jersey-jackson-json-date-format-serialization-how-to-change-the-format-or-us) for more