# Date serialization ignores ContextResolver in REST request

Tags: json, jax-rs, wildfly, jsonb, yasson

I have an application based on Wildfly 15, which uses Yasson to serialize entities in REST requests. I use the javaee-api 8.0.1 and created a `ContextResolver` for configuring the date serialization format like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56300246/584532.

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JsonbDateConfig implements ContextResolver<Jsonb> {
  // ...
}
```

However, when sending REST requests using the following code, the configuration is ignored (no debugging breakpoint in the methods of `JsonbDateConfig` is triggered).

```
Response response = target.path(REST_SERVICE_NAME)
  .request()
  .post(Entity.entity(dataTO, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Consequently, the resulting JSON contains an inproperly formatted date value.

I could create a `JsonbAdapter` and add the annotation `@JsonbTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)` to the field of type `java.util.Date`. However, I prefer a solution that applies to all date fields. What is the solution with the `ContextResolver` not working?

Note that Wildfly loads my implementation class of `ContextResolver` during startup (class loading breakpoint) and this resolver is used when I receive incoming REST requests.

Comment: What date type are you using? Is it a `java.util.Date`?

Comment: Yes, it is `java.util.Date`.

Comment: My assumption is, though I have not read the spec, that the client does not process through the `ContextResolver`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a JAX-RS client you need to register the provider with the client.

```
Response response = target.path(REST_SERVICE_NAME)
  .register(JsonbDateConfig.class)
  .request()
  .post(Entity.entity(dataTO, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working. Do you happen to know if it is possible to globally register the provider with all rest clients?

Comment: I suppose you could have a global `ClientConfig` that could be shared.